# How do I store persistent data?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game which uses cookies (NOM NOM NOM cookies, not web browser cookies) as currency.

```
var cookies = 0;
function cookieClick(number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
}
```

Now I need to save the number of cookies so that when the user refreshes the page the number of cookies will persist.

How do I do this?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what cookies are. You might want to read some tutorials before asking questions here.

Comment: also look into your local storage model...whichever way you choose, note that browsers only have access to their own storage mechanisms and you may not use the file system of your user

Comment: Im making idle game where im using cookies as money, Im trying to find a function to save my cookies so when leave the page and come back so I stil have the amount cookies I had when I left.

Comment: Yes, local storage, but don't know how it works. I found it on some web page but didnt uderstand it.

Comment: @LasseHaslund LocalStorage is basically a property on window that persists  and doesn't get cleared every time a user navigates (see docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Storage
>
> The Storage interface of the Web Storage API provides access to the session storage or local storage for a particular domain, allowing you to for example add, modify or delete stored data items.
>
> If you want to manipulate the session storage for a domain, you call **Window.sessionStorage** method; If you want to manipulate the local storage for a domain, you call **Window.localStorage**.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Store the value of `cookies` in `Window.localStorage` to make it stay until the user clears the cache, or `Window.sessionStorage` to make it stay until the user closes the browser window. Then update the value on page load if it exists.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/0k3c0x2x/1/))

```
var cookies = 0;
if(localStorage.cookies) cookies = localStorage.getItem('cookies');
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
function cookieClick(number){
    cookies = parseInt(cookies) + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
    localStorage.setItem('cookies', cookies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't mean for **cookies** what we all mean here. You simply need to store a counter called `cookies`, apparently.

You can use `window.localStorage`, as suggested.

```
function consumeCookies (n) {
    var n = n ? n : 1;
    var util = localStorage.getItem("util");
    util = util ? util : "{}";
    util = JSON.parse(util);
    util.cookies = util.cookies ? util.cookies + n : n;
    util = JSON.stringify(util);
    return localStorage.setItem("util", util);
}
// For consuming 42 cookies ...
consumeCookies(42);
```

Note that here an entire *bag* of properties is stored, not just a plain `(key,value)`. This might be a better design choice, but it's up to your taste.

In the same namespace you could store other properties now, the name of the player for instance:

```
function loadUtil () {
    var util = localStorage.getItem("util");
    util = util ? util : "{}";
    util = JSON.parse(util);
    return util;
}

function storeUtil (util) {
    return localStorage.setItem("util", JSON.stringify(util));
}

function setName (name) {
    var util = loadUtil();
    util.name = name ? name : "Ulysses";
    return storeUtil(util);
}
```

and easily access the entire JSON in other part of your application.

Check out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/er67egvy/).

Though this might be a little overkill and probably in that case another better choice is to prefer.